# Google Geocode API Filtering

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am trying to use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) and there does not seem to be a way to filter by multiple states. I can filter by one state (Ex. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Elm+St&components=administrative_area:WA|country:US&key=API_KEY)

Does anyone know how to filter by multiple states?

Comment: What results are you trying to achieve? Are you wanting a list of all the states that have `Elm St` in them?

Comment: I've done a bit more digging since this post and from what I can tell it doesn't look like what I want to achieve is possible. So in short, list only the Elm Streets in WA, ID, and OR like so (or other methods to achieve the same results).

components=administrative_area:WA,ID,OR

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to achieve this with the Google API, but I do know how to do it with the [SmartyStreets Autocomplete API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/autocomplete).

A simple `GET` request with the `state_filter` option will do what you want. Here is an example:

```
curl "https://autocomplete-api.smartystreets.com/suggest?prefix=Elm+St&state_filter=wa,id,or&auth-id=<your-auth-id>"
```

Broken out we see these parameters:

```
hostname: autocomplete-api.smartystreets.com
prefix: Elm St
state_filter: WA,ID,OR
auth-id: <a-valid-smartystreets-auth-id>
```

The `prefix` should be part of an address that you are looking for. The Autocomplete API is used for suggesting addresses as users type an address into an address field in a web form. But you can access it directly to achieve your stated purpose.

The results of this request would be a `JSON` string:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        {
            "text": "Elm St, Bellevue ID",
            "street_line": "Elm St",
            "city": "Bellevue",
            "state": "ID"
        },
        {
            "text": "W Elm St, Almira WA",
            "street_line": "W Elm St",
            "city": "Almira",
            "state": "WA"
        },
        {
            "text": "Elm St SW, Albany OR",
            "street_line": "Elm St SW",
            "city": "Albany",
            "state": "OR"
        },
        // 7 other results were truncated
    ]
}
```

Note: To use any of the SmartyStreets APIs, you need a valid `auth-id`, which you can get easily when you signup for a free account.

(Disclaimer: I work for SmartyStreets)